# Advertise the twitterbot on beta sites in alternation with the newsletter

Tags: feature-request, twitter, beta-phase, site-promotion

All sites (beta, graduated, or Programmers) have a twitter bot. Like [this one](http://twitter.com/StackRobotics). It's a great idea, helps publicize the site effectively if the bot has enough followers.

But:

[image]

And, without followers, you have effectively nobody who'll read the posts and retweet them. So the bot is pretty much ineffective.

Why aren't there followers? Simple. Nearly nobody knows about the twitterbots--only loony guys like me who lurk around the metas.

A graduated site can use a community ad to publicize the bot. But, beta sites are helpless here.

On the other hand, beta sites *do* have this:

[image]

which may be a useful too but is useless in publicizing the site.

So, to my actual feature request:

#### Could the newsletter ad space sometimes show an ad for the twitterbot?

Comment: Needs to be done in the style of a personals ad: "Twitterbot: [lookin pa nub](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgFDv_4oKsw)".